# Fixed Button Loses Functionality After Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= 75) {
            $('#ticketDetailsButtons').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 75
            });
        } else {
            $('#ticketDetailsButtons').css({
                position: 'static'
            });
        }
    });
```

After its position value is changed to static, I can't click it anymore, I can only see it. Any ideas?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzp7f/

Comment: [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Having the code of the event handler and the markup of the button would be helpful as well.

Comment: The button can be clicked in the fiddle, scrolled or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've got another element with a higher `z-index` covering the button. Would be helpful to see your HTML.